# VirtualBox Scroll Up/Down Guest Terminal

Tags: virtualbox, scrolling

I have a [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/) guest on a Windows XP host.

BSD has no GUI, so it just boots up to the terminal. The output of most commands is more than is visible on the screen, but I can't scroll up/down in the terminal through <kbd>Page Up</kbd> / <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, or  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  +  <kbd>Page Up / Down</kbd> keys.

I have to keep running commands like `ls` as  `ls | less` which is annoying if the output is a lot.

How can I scroll the screen output?

Answer (score 20):

If you'd like to scroll up/down in VirtualBox terminal window, use please the combination key:
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd>

For leave terminal window, just press the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: I did say in my question `I can't scroll up/down in the terminal through Page Up/Page Down, or SHIFT+Page Up/Down keys`

Comment: Ups... I missed SHIFT notice... so sorry.

Comment: Anyway you helped for others like me who also not read the question precisily.

Answer (score 6):

If you are on a Mac with no Page Up/Page Down keys, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>

Comment: it works with linux too

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly what you asked, but it is a usable workaround: after starting up your VirtualBox, connect to it with a ssh client like putty. You can then work and scroll in the ssh client, instead of using the VirtualBox terminal.

With Virtualbox, the guest should be connected to the network using Bridge Adapter instead of NAT for connecting via SSH with Putty.